# Translating set definition to English

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The definition of the union set between two sets is: $$A \cup B = \{x | x\in A \lor x\in B\}$$
How do you say this in English? Do you say '$A \cup B$ is the set of all elements $x$, such that $x$ is an element of $A$ or $x$ is an element of $B$'? Isn't this the same as saying $\forall x ( x\in A \lor x \in B)$.

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: You're translation into English is correct.  $\forall x(x\in A \vee x \in B)$ is a *statement* that tells you that every $x$ *is* in $A$ or in $B$ while $\{x\mid x\in A \vee x \in B\}$ is the *set* of all of the $x$ that happen to be in $A$ or in $B$.  Do you see the difference?

Comment: What has ‘belongs to’ have to see with the euro symbol ;o)

Comment: The set notation and the logical sentence are not the same. The first is describing a set and the second is saying that all $x$ are contained in the union of $A$ and $B$. The commonality is in that they involve the union.

Comment: you're translation works perfectly, by the way I know your dilemma and in a case like this it has been proved helpful to consult for example the English wiki source like [union of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory))...@Bernard: I guess in this case the *union* doesn't consider to kick the $x$ out